# Not able call a local method from setUpClass

Tags: python, unit-testing

My code:

```
class TestSystemPromotion(unittest2.TestCase):

  @classmethod
  def setUpClass(self):
    ...
    self.setup_test_data()
    ..

  def test_something(self):
    ...

  def setup_test_data(self):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest2.main()
```

Error which I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: unbound method setup_test_data() must be called with TestSystemPromotion
instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't call instance methods from class methods. Either consider using `setUp` instead, or make `setup_test_data` a class method too. Also, it's better if you called the argument `cls` instead of `self` to avoid the confusion - the first argument to the class method is the class, not the instance. The instance (`self`) doesn't exist at all when `setUpClass` is called.

```
class TestSystemPromotion(unittest2.TestCase):

  @classmethod
  def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.setup_test_data()


  @classmethod
  def setup_test_data(cls):
    ...

  def test_something(self):
    ...
```

Or:

```
class TestSystemPromotion(unittest2.TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    self.setup_test_data()

  def setup_test_data(self):
    ...

  def test_something(self):
    ...
```

For better comprehension, you can think of it this way: `cls == type(self)`

Comment: Is this still true in Python 2.7+? I've been able to do `setUpClass(self)` and define some accessible `self.var` variables therein that I can then `super` in child classes, and the children understand them.